# How To change Background color of Action Bar sherlock Spinner DropDown Dynamically?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am using `sherlock activity` bar spinner dropdown for my app and i would like to change the background  color as now i am getting same color as default. 
I am Using

`final String[] actions = new String[] { "WorkArea", "project1","project2", "project3" };`

and

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item, actions);             getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

ActionBar.OnNavigationListener navigationListener = new OnNavigationListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Current Action : "actions[itemPosition],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return false;
                } };
 getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, navigationListener);
 adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

I am getting like [image] I want like [image]

can i change the background color  here ?? If Yes, Any Suggestion Please. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to change your theme ?

In your manifest file, set your theme with the following :

> ```
> <application
>     android:theme="@style/Sherlock.__Theme.DarkActionBar">
> ```

You can create your own actionbar style easily by using a web generator like [Action bar style generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/)